# How to config prettier to format long lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier, prettier-vscode

How can I config prettier to format long lines like this:

```
  return src(`${jsFolder}/libraries/*.js`, { since: lastRun(jsCopyTask) })
    .pipe(dest(`${distFolder}/assets/js`))
```

And not like this:

```
  return src(`${jsFolder}/libraries/*.js`, { since: lastRun(jsCopyTask) }).pipe(
    dest(`${distFolder}/assets/js`)
  )
```

Here Prettier is breaking the function args instead of the chain functions.

If this is not possible using Prettier is there an alternative for this?